# приоритет отображения

Tags: html

У меня есть див со слайдером, и див с надписью, но див со слайдером отображается как бы на передовой, и надпись за ним не видно, как сделать чтобы див с надписью был на передовой, а див со слайдером уже за ним?

Comment: с помощью z-index

Comment: Без примера непонятно. Но попробуй z-index покрутить

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Без верстки и стилей можно просто угадывать.